# Why is a large flatlist slow? How can I use shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just want to confirm I have this right.

My understanding is that a long flatlist in react native without pureComponent will update the state of each object in the list. So if you have a horizontal flatlist:

```
array = [A, B, C, D, E]

with a horizontal flatlist rendered to look like:

A | B | C | D | E
```

Then each page will be updated even if nothing  in the state changes for A-D but one thing changes in page E.

My understanding is that a PureComponent overcomes this by doing a shallow comparison of the array to see if anything has changed, and only if there is a change, say E turns to F, then only that particular page updates.

If this is correct, then how do you overcome deep changes to nested arrays?

For example:

```
array = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
```

In the above case, if I change array[2][2] to 10 instead of 9, the PureComponent would overlook that because it only does shallow comparison. So what I do in my app right now is this.forceUpdate(), but I believe that causes a rerender of each page. so how could I use PureComponent without forceUpdate? I think it is through shouldComponentUpdate, but idk. Keep in mind I cannot change the data structure to something other than nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It was better to attach code.

For flatlist performance, you have to page data and as user scrolls, you give more data to it

For updating flat list use assign this.state to it and update its data as flatlist members.

```
<FlatList
extraData={this.state}
/>
```

If you use PureComponent for your flatList members it may not update. Personally I sent events to update only specific members to reduce the required update process but for a quick fix, you can make your items Component instead.